# RIGHT\LEFT Join does not provide null values without condition

Tags: sql-server, tableau-api

I have two tables one is the lookup table and the other is the data table. The lookup table has columns named cycleid, cycle. The data table has SID, cycleid, cycle. Below is the structure of the tables.

[image: Data Table]

[image: Lookup Table]

If you check the data table, the SID may have all the cycles and may not have all the cycles. I want to output the SID completed as well as missed cycles.

I right joined the lookup table and retrieved the missing as well as completed cycles. Below is the query I used.

```
    SELECT TOP 1000 [SID]
          ,s4.[CYCLE]
          ,s4.[CYCLEID]
      FROM [dbo].[data] s3 RIGHT JOIN
[dbo].[lookup_data] s4 ON s3.CYCLEID = s4.CYCLEID
```

The query is not displaying me the missed values when I query for all the SID's. When I specifically query for a SID with the below query i am getting the correct result including the missed ones.

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [SID]
      ,s4.[CYCLE]
      ,s4.[CYCLEID]
  FROM [dbo].[data] s3 RIGHT JOIN [dbo].[lookup_data] s4 
  ON s3.CYCLEID = s4.CYCLEID 
  AND s3.SID = 101002
  ORDER BY [SID], s4.[CYCLEID]
```

As I am supplying this query into tableau I cannot provide the sid value in the query. I want to return all the sid's and from tableau I will be do the rest of the things.

The expected output that i need is as shown below.

[image: Expected Output]

I wrote a cross join query like below to acheive my expected output

```
  SELECT DISTINCT
            tab.CYCLEID
           ,tab.SID
           ,d.CYCLE
  FROM      ( SELECT    d.SID
                       ,d.[CYCLE]
                       ,e.CYCLEID
              FROM      ( SELECT    e.sid
                                   ,e.CYCLE
                          FROM      [db_temp].[dbo].[Sheet3$] e
                        ) d
              CROSS JOIN [db_temp].[dbo].[Sheet4$] e
            ) tab
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [db_temp].[dbo].[Sheet3$] d
  ON        d.CYCLEID = tab.CYCLEID
            AND d.SID = tab.SID
  ORDER BY  tab.SID
           ,tab.CYCLEID;
```

However I am not able to use this query for more scenarios as my data set have nearly 20 to 40 columns and i am having issues when i use the above one.

Is there any way to do this in a simpler manner with only left or right join itself? I want the query to return all the missing values and the completed values for the all the SID's instead of supplying a single sid in the query.

Comment: Do you have the same order by in the first query? Can it be that the first query doesn't have the order by so you're just not seeing them in the 1000 records result?

Comment: The order by does not have any impact. I have just used it to have a sort order so that i can show the data based on the SID, CycleID.

Comment: In fact, could you provide us the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a master table first (combine all `SID` and `CYCLE ID`), then right join with the data table

```
;with ctxMaster as (
    select distinct d.SID, l.CYCLE, l.CYCLEID
    from lookup_data l
    cross join data d
)
select d.SID, m.CYCLE, m.CYCLEID
from ctxMaster m
left join data d on m.SID = d.SID and m.CYCLEID = d.CYCLEID
order by m.SID, m.CYCLEID
```

[Fiddle](http://rextester.com/GYUGZJ81958)

Or if you don't want to use common table expression, subquery version:

```
select d.SID, m.CYCLE, m.CYCLEID
from (select distinct d.SID, l.CYCLE, l.CYCLEID
      from lookup_data l
      cross join data d) m
left join data d on m.SID = d.SID and m.CYCLEID = d.CYCLEID
order by m.SID, m.CYCLEID
```

Comment: Hi Alex, I already have this code. I want more simpler one. I will tell my problems in using this type of code. I will pass this sql in the tableau as direct query data source and I have data more than 1 lakh. The tableau view will be accessed by nearly 100 users and everytime this code will run on the sql for these 100 users when they refresh the view. This will reduce my performance. So I need a simpler code.

Comment: Then it's not the issue about the SQL, is how your present the data in tableau.  I'm not sure how you design your worksheet, but normally I will pass the `lookup_data` and `data` into tableau, and let it join in tableau, as the record is the least and can have possible calculation in tableau with calculated field, but that will be another story for performance impact with too much calculated field.

Comment: You are welcome, but in tableau, try to reuse the data instead of build up in data layer.  You will lost a lot of detail, and it will be painful when you need to present those details (add another data source or replace the data source, first one will increase the data size, last one will kill you, I tried last one ...)